# Camera in landscape mode not in fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift, camera, fullscreen

I've made a camera app. In portrait mode it looks like that:
[image]

but in landscape mode it isn't fullscreen so what could be the reason?

[image]

Here is the takePhoto function:

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
        var imageViewBackground: UIImageView!
        self.fullScreenView.hidden = false
        self.recordButton.enabled = false
        self.takephoto.enabled = false
        self.recordButton.hidden = true
        self.takephoto.hidden = true

        session.startRunning()

        // add the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to the view and sets the view in fullscreen
        fullScreenView.frame = view.bounds
        fullScreenView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

        // add action to fullScreenView
        gestureFullScreenView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.takePhoto(_:)))
        self.fullScreenView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureFullScreenView)

        // add action to myView
        gestureView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.setFrontpage(_:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureView)

        if (preview == true) {
            if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
                // code for photo capture goes here...

                stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                    // process the image data (sampleBuffer) here to get an image file we can put in our view

                    if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                        let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                        let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                        let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                        let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                        self.fullScreenView.hidden = true
                        self.fullScreenView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach(self.fullScreenView.removeGestureRecognizer)
                        self.session.stopRunning()

                        // save image to the library
                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

                        imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height))
                        imageViewBackground.image = image
                        imageViewBackground.tag = self.key

                        self.view.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            preview = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: pls update the question with relevant code. How are you starting the camera ?

Comment: i posted the takephoto method

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate the device, the views get adjusted based on the device orientation. In your case, as you are adding the `videoPreviewLayer`, it will not resized properly. You have to do it on your own.

Change the frame of `videoPreviewLayer` when the device is rotated. Or call the method again, when you rotate the device.

Comment: And do you have an idea where to set the frame of the videoPreviewLayer?